# How to give the value of an array element for a value in the formbuilder group?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular2-formbuilder, angular-formbuilder

I want to populate the dropdown in angular reactive form through the data obtained from endpoint. It is created as a FormArray as follows. userDetailsData is the data object which is store the data obtained through the backend.

```js
this.userDetailsData.user_context.forEach(async data => {
       const userContext = this.createJobForm.get('user_context') as FormArray;
        this.parent_id = this.parentList.find(parent => parent.parent_name === data.parent_name)?.id;
        this.toyList = this.parentList.filter(toy => toy.id === this.parent_id).flatMap(item => item.toys);
        await this.getUsersList();
        this.userIdentifier = this.userList.find(user => user.name === data.username)?.identifier;

        userContext.insert(0, this.formBuilder.group({
            parent_id: [this.parent_id, [Validators.required]],
            user_identifier: [this.userIdentifier],
            dynamic_users: [this.isUserAvailble ? true : false],
            toy_id: [this.toyList[0].id]  // Beacuse of this, only the first toy id in the array is always set.
        }));
    });
```

```json
[
    {
        "id": "A1450D375-7257-4555F5-BA30-DF246ED6E",
        "type": "toy",
        "parent_name": "admin",
        "toy_name": "Test_Toy12"
    },
    {
        "id": "6A0EC-185A-DF-80A-FD7BB298CE2gDERTF",
        "type": "toy",
        "parent_name": "admin",
         "toy_name": "Test_Toy56"
    }
]
```

The toyList returns an array like this. How to dynamically set the id as the value of the toy_id of the  formBuilder.group?

Comment: Could you provide the code on stackblitz.com to reproduce your issue?

Comment: will try to add a stackblitz. I hope you understand my issue. @MernaMustafa

Answer (score 0):

Write some html that will create a dropdown list for the user. Then you can attach the `formControlName` to the dropdown, that will bind `toy_id` to the selected `toy`.

Here's a simplified example of the above:

```
    <form [formGroup]="form">
      <div *ngIf="f.length > 0">
        <div *ngFor="let context of f.controls; let i = index">
          <div [formGroup]="context">
            <ng-container>
              <select name="cars" id="cars" formControlName="toy_id" [(ngModel)]="selectedToyId">
                <option *ngFor="let item of toyList" [value]="item.id">{{item.toy_name}}</option>
              </select>
            </ng-container>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-example-jpjag6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: I got this error when I'm using ```[(ngModel)]``` It looks like you're using ngModel on the same form field as formControlName. Support for using the ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with reactive form directives has been deprecated in Angular v6 and will be removed in a future version of Angular

Comment: I have provided a stackblitz demo in the answer where the code is working totally fine w/o any errors. So, have you put any effort to resolve the error you are getting, other than posting your comment?